# Which ojdbc version supports oracle 12.1 with tomcat 6?

Tags: java, database, oracle12c

I want to connect oracle 12.1 with tomcat 6 and JDK 6.The thing i can change only is ojdbc version.I tried ojdbc 6,7,8 but getting same authentication issue

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

Comment: ojdbc7 should work fine.  THere is something else causing the problem.  Can you install the oracle client and do a tnsping?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_02

Comment: @OldProgrammer  @ a_horse_with_no_name thankyou guys for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem got resolved by placing ojdbc6 in lib folder of tomcat.